# About the pseudoinverse $A^{+}$ in Gilbert Strang's "Linear Algebra and its Applications 2nd Edition".

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, pseudoinverse

[image]

I am reading Gilbert Strang's "Linear Algebra and its Applications 2nd Edition".

He wrote "All solutions of $A \overline{x} = p$ share this same component $\overline{x_r}$ in the row space, and differ only in the nullspace component $w$".

I cannot understand why this fact is true.

Please tell me the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\bar x$ satisfies $A \bar x = p$. Let $w = \bar x - \bar x_r$, and notice that $A w = A \bar x - A \bar x_r = p - p = 0$. This shows that $\bar x$ can be written as
$$
\bar x = \bar x_r + w,
$$
where $w \in N(A)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, littleO.